# How can I install ngx-bootstrap in project Angular 17?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

How can I install ngx-boostrap in an Angular 17 project? In his manual installation guide, he asks to install ngx-boostrap via npm and then add the Bootstrap import to the NgModule annotation, but in the Angular 17 version it is no longer used. What can I do about it?

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

```
  import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
   
  @NgModule({
    …
    imports: [ TooltipModule.forRoot(), … ]
    …
  })
```

find out how to install ngx-boostrap in an Angular 17 project

Answer (score 0):

When you need to create a new Angular project, add this in your command line:

```
--no-standalone
```

E.g.,

```
ng new your-app-angular --no-standalone
```

With Angular CLI 17, this option was `standaolne=false`. This is why you do not have a file `app.module` in your project.

Comment: In this case, I would like to use Angular 17, which has this autonomous structure.